# Why are the texts not been lemmatized based on the feature results?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, nltk

Using the following customized tokenizer

```
class LemmaTokenizer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
    def __call__(self, articles):
        result = [self.wnl.lemmatize(t) for t in word_tokenize(articles)]
       # print(result)
        return result
```

and after some preprocessing steps,

```
descript_data= descript_data.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
descript_data= descript_data.str.replace('\d+', ' ')
descript_data= descript_data.str.replace(r'(\b\w{1,2}\b)', ' ')
descript_data= descript_data.str.replace('[^\w\s]', ' ')
```

I ran the following:

```
vect = TfidfVectorizer(strip_accents = 'ascii', 
                       stop_words = 'english', 
                       lowercase = True, 
                       max_df = 0.8, 
                       min_df = 10,
                       analyzer='word',
                       tokenizer=LemmaTokenizer()) 

final = vect.fit_transform(descript_data)
print(vect.get_feature_names())
```

where the `descript_data` is the column of texts data.
It still gets both the original words and its complement word with 's', 'ly', etc. in the result.
How could I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Using the code given for the following example sentences, there is no problem. There could be some problem in the pre-processing steps.

```py
#Invoke libraries
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

class LemmaTokenizer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
    def __call__(self, articles):
        result = [self.wnl.lemmatize(t) for t in word_tokenize(articles)]
        #print(result)
        return result

#build example sentences with plural and singular words to check lemmatization
d = ["this is a good song by this singer",
     "there are other songs that are better from other singers"]

#note that the max_df and min_df are commented as the sample size is too small
vect = TfidfVectorizer(strip_accents = 'ascii', 
                       stop_words = 'english', 
                       lowercase = True, 
                       #max_df = 0.8, 
                       #min_df = 10,
                       analyzer='word',
                       tokenizer=LemmaTokenizer()) 

final = vect.fit_transform(d)
print(vect.get_feature_names())

#output. Note that there is no "singers" or "songs"
[u'better', u'good', u'singer', u'song']
```

Comment: please paste a couple of lines from  `descript_data` so one could reproduce the error.

Comment: https://filebin.net/svc7mkv1nsuqx86v for the description column